# Html video support different video src type

Tags: javascript, css, video, html5-video

I'm working with video here I want to embed tag support youtube or Vimeo video's both of these types but it is working with youtube video only not with Vimeo. Is there any other format to write can anyone suggest me in the right direction.

```html
<embed width="600" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">
```

I had tried like this `<embed width="800" height="500" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY">` which is working fine when i replaced with vimeo link `https://vimeo.com/47041550` it is not working.

Comment: Show what you tried, explain what exactly is not working! (I just tried the URL from the embed code for a Vimeo video in your `embed` element, and that _worked fine_.) Also, explain why you want to use embed instead of iframe?

Comment: @04FS when i had tried vimeo with embed tag it is not working can you post snippet of your code

Comment: Show what _you_ tried. That info belongs into a proper question to begin with; you don’t just _say_ stuff wasn’t working, without showing what exactly you did in the first place.

Comment: @04FS I updated my question check it.

Comment: For the YouTube video, you took the actual embed URL they provide - whereas with the Vimeo one, you just tried to place the complete Vimeo _page_ that contains the video into the embed element. So, solution simple: Go get the actual embed URL for the Vimeo video …

Comment: @04FS Thanks I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use iframe.

**Youtube**

> < iframe width = '560' height = '315' style = 'max-width:100%;' src =
>   'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{youtube-id}' frameborder = '0'
>   allowfullscreen >< /iframe >

**Vimeo**

> < iframe width = '560' height = '315' style = 'max-width:100%;' src =
>   'https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video-id}' frameborder = '0'
>   allowfullscreen>< /iframe >

Answer (score 0):

try in iframe like that:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

only need to be set by css what u want

Comment: without using iframe

Answer (score 0):

in vimeo there is a share button. when you click it, you will get the embed code of the video

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76995667?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/76995667">pitch videos</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/user888285">tony benna</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>`

similarly in YouTube, there is a share button, where you get the embed code